# How to get booze to Mars?

Tags: internal-consistency, near-future, planets

Hooray! Clickbait worked! Now for the question:

**Is it even possible to get alcohol to Mars colony under these circumstances?**

Situation: We have base on Mars. Mars missions are on level of "ISS missions": Regular human presence is established on Mars. About 10 - 15 people live constantly inside small Martian colony.

This colony is full independent as of water, oxygen and power (ice resources + solar power). Colony can cover about 95% of food demand, rest is delivered by resupply missions.

Astronauts go on 4 year mission to Mars and back. Every two years resupply mission lands with 5 new crew members and after a while 5 of "veterans" go back to Earth.

**Space agencies involved:**

- NASA (USA)
- ESA (EU)
- Roskosmos (Russia)
- JASA (Japan)
- CSA ASC (Canada)

Now, back to the clickbait question. The astronauts in the colony would like to have some alcoholic refreshments available. However, because space travel is still hard and dangerous and Martian colony can have serious issues any time, as a contingency plan all of drugs and alcohol are strictly forbidden on any Mars missions.

While astronauts are aware of the fact that all of them being drunk or even lightly tipsy can be dangerous to the mission, or maybe even lethal, they also know that most severe incident required cooperation of three astronauts in order to estabilish "normal" status.

(So, in other calculations, two astronauts can be drunk like Czech and the mission can most probably survive)

The thing is:

- All equipment on Mars base is monitored and all "food" related equipment usage is being reported to the mission control (to know how much food to deliver)
- All laboratory equipment is also monitored and mission control is trying to have all laboratory equipment utilized
- All equipment being delivered to Mars go through several checks and is cataloged

All astronauts are trained and go through psychology tests to make sure they will go through 4 years without any problem.

But the thing is, the Martian nights are long and even if its really thrilling to be there out in the wild and explore the unexplored, one would surely enjoy the empty emptiness of Mars with glass of something "spicy"

Are we able to fulfill the needs of Astronauts?

Comment: I wonder if mission psychologist would really think 4 years prohibition a good idea.

Comment: Our species has had thousands of years to develop various means of smuggling and getting contraband past detection.  This is just the next step of that evolution.

Comment: I agree with @Mołot, It would be far better for the colony if they allowed some indulgences in controlled manner (so not everyone is drunk at the same time) rather than outright prohibition. Alcohol consumption have always been at the highest rate during prohibition eras and it has also been the times where gangsters have earned tons of cash from bootlegging - smuggling will occur if they try to have a zero tolerance.

Comment: So really you are just asking how to smuggle goods through a system...that it is in space is irrelevant...its also kinda story based...since the only one who knows whether things can be hidden, or people bribed, is you.

Comment: @Mołot, Mrkvicka - Alcohol consumption is not a human need, is a practice created by social convention.  I personally went decades without drinking a drop without any issue because I never saw the benefit.  If the culture of the group is one that also does not see the benefit (or one that sees the risks outweighing the benefits), prohibition is not likely to be enforced only by "mission control" but also by everyone else there.  If the martians do want to drink however then yes, like Dinosaurs in Jurassic Park, they will find a way and attempting to prevent it may have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: @GrinningX I don't think either user meant to suggest it was a *need*, and social convention is not something to be considered as trivial. Nor can one realistically suppose that the astronauts are free from social norms, desire for comfort, or (in the extreme case) addiction.

Comment: "Drugs & alcohol strictly forbidden"?  Given that this is in a place that at its closest is at least 46 million miles (54 million km) from the nearest DEA office, just how do you expect it to be enforced?

Comment: @DBPriGuy - I am not saying social norms are trivial, just that they are unique to their societies.  I actually stated that if their martian culture did want to drink stopping it would have unforeseen consequences.  When you have 5 people walking a fine line between life and death though, you may find that the local culture is not one of tolerance for alcohol/drugs.  It just seems very... American-centric... to quote Prohibition whenever anyone talks about taking alcohol out of the equation.  It can absolutely be removed safely, given the right social conditions.

Comment: @GrinningX in this question we are clearly talking about people from a drinking culture - and in situation where astronauts were not chosen for abstinency.

Comment: @GrinningX Why is it American-centric to talk about what happened during a prohibition period? USA is not the only country that have tried to totally ban alcohol; every country which tried it has underwent almost the exact same consequences as USA did.

Comment: Even in prison, creative inmates hoard fermentable food and make pruno:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruno  The one wrinkle I see is that on Mars, there's no wild yeast spores floating in the air, but smuggling a (minute) sample of (dried) yeast seems feasible.

Comment: @Catalyst I do agree that smuggling yeast is highly likely to happen (and highly likely to succeed since you only need minute quantities); however there will be free spores in the air as it will be impossible to prevent it from sneaking on board the ships (it's on food, it's on clothes, it's on skin...).

Comment: @Mrkvička - It's American-centric because it's the only argument Americans ever use.  To illustrate the greater world context though, Saudi Arabia, the UAE, Iran, Iraq, parts of India as "dry" countries where consumption is illegal and generally frowned upon.  Pakistan also bans alcohol consumption for non-Muslims.  To reiterate myself for the third time, alcohol consumption is a cultural thing only, and assuming that everyone wants it is a poor assumption.  As with ANYTHING though, trying to ban something desired by a culture is, generally, a bad idea and the ban will be circumvented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why bring the booze all the way across space when you can make it right there on Mars?**

This would immediately circumvent this problem:

> All equipment being delivered to Mars go through several checks and is cataloged

Now, the astronauts still have a couple problems to get around:

> All equipment on Mars base is monitored and all "food" related equipment usage is being reported to the mission control (to know how much food to deliver)

But by whom? After all, unless mission control has a camera on every crate of supplies, it's likely up to the astronauts to report their food usage. Thus, whoever is reporting the food usage can *lie*. This detail is important:

> Colony can cover about 95% of food demand, rest is delivered by resupply missions.

This seems to imply that the colonists are growing some of their food. So what they can do is to lie about just what and how much they are growing. Let's suppose they fill a few plots with barley, hops, and wheat, and just so happen to *forget* these crops when reporting them to mission control.

Okay. We have our raw materials for our tasty Martian Surprise. But we need something to brew it in. I know! Our lab equipment! Oh, but wait:

> All laboratory equipment is also monitored and mission control is trying to have all laboratory equipment utilized

But our clever astronauts can figure their way around this. One way would again be to lie about what they're using it for: Propose to use the equipment for some scientific study, then fabricate the results. Or they could lie and say the equipment was broken en route, and they're keeping it in the storage closet that oh-so-happens to have no cameras until it can be picked up and sent back to Earth. Heck, if they really want to sell the lie, they can break a nonessential-to-brewing part of the equipment itself.

If they're feeling *really* gutsy, they could propose a scientific experiment that requires brewing equipment. Something like "Activity of Yeast in Martian Gravity". This way they could even have commercial yeast sent to them to really get going!

P.S. Supposing that MC *does* have cameras and surveillance on what exactly is being grown at base, it's worth noting that just about *anything* can be fermented, so it doesn't necessarily have to be crops as suspicious as the three I mentioned above.

P.P.S I think the study of Martian viticulture promises to be a *fascinating* field, don't you?

Comment: Most of unmalted stuff needs enzyme addition to ferment, or special mix of microbes. With exception of fruit. I imagine malting barley wouldn't be trivial.

Comment: As an addendum:  certainly there will be chemists on Mars who will fully understand the chemistry of fermentation.  Besides, there will be plenty of bacteria crawling around that the colonists brought with them.  It won't take long to breed a strain that makes really nice alcohol.

Comment: @Mołot This is true though I was simply listing examples. For all that it matters, the astronauts could  grow potatoes, beets, berries, apples, grapes, rice, corn, dandelion, sugar, cactus, etc. all for the purpose of producing alcoholic beverages.

Comment: @Mołot All you need for fermentation is yeast (well, plus water, sugars and spices such as hops), and however much you sterilize you will get yeast with you up. [It won't be lager, but it will do the trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambic)

Comment: @Mrkvička have you read what you link?! Lambic is made with mix of yeast and bacteria. And most of spontaneous mixes in home environment will give you vinegar or cesspit. I have few years of brewing experience to back up that claim. Anyway, ask on homebrew stack exchange if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Mołot I never said it would be easy or taste good (in the end, if you are desperate to get drunk, you will drink hand sanitizer). My point is that all you need is yeast and you will have it around you, with a couple of attempts they will have their own Martian brew. The reason for the link was just to point out that people still use spontaneous fermentation (which was the way all brews were before we figured out that it was yeast causing it). If none of them manages to get the fermentation to work, then eventually someone will smuggle a good strain of yeast.

Comment: @Mołot as long as you're going to distill it afterwards, brewing "cesspit" is perfectly sufficient - as long as you have some yeast (any! baker's yeast will do) and you can do it cleanly to kill vinegar-producing bacteria, you can ferment pretty much anything, separate the horribly tasting parts and potentially poisonous byproducts from pure ethanol, and then use it for artificially flavoured engineered strong drinks.

Comment: Consider that alcohol is produced in many (most?) prisons. Your Martian explorers have two advantages over those prisoners, no snap inspections and scientific/engineering training for the would-be brewers. http://people.howstuffworks.com/prison-toilet-wine.htm

Comment: Even given that monitoring &c exists, who's going to enforce those restrictions, and how?

Comment: @jamesqf The astronauts return after a certain amount of time, at which point they would face official sanctions from whatever country they hail from.

Comment: @Karl Aerating wort is a mandatory step in brewing on a small scale. Only way to go without it is a really, really large pitch size. Learn before you talk and show your ignorance.

Comment: @DBPriGuy: Your space agency is going to do that to public heros?  Sure they are :-)

Comment: @Molot Yikes. Uhm, one; be nice. Two; comments are not for extended discussion, please move to chat

Comment: @Mołot Aerating wort should be done before adding the yeast and at that point it won't produce any vinegar. You need oxygen at the start to allow the yeast to get going, but they will only produce ethanol while in an oxygen deprived environment (if they ferment in oxygen rich environment, then they only produce CO2). Vinegar is produced when acetic acid bacteria ferment sugars or ethanol in an oxygen rich environment. The AA bacteria is killed by the boiling and later contamination is kept in check by the lack of O2. Any vinegar produced means you got O2 in at the wrong time of the process.

Comment: @Mrkvička These comments have been becoming increasingly irrelevant to the answer. Please move this conversation to chat.